# Prove vector-valued function is differentiable

Tags: derivatives, vector-analysis

Give $D$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f: D\to \mathbb{R}^p$ is differentiable on $D$. Supposing that $f$ has second derivative at $x_0\in D$.

For every $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$, give $g: D\to \mathbb{R}^p$ define by $$g(x)=f'(x)(u), \forall x\in D.$$
Prove that $g$ is differentiable at $x_0$ and $g'(x_0)(v)=f^{(2)}(x_0)(u,v)$.

My attempt:

Give $h\in \mathbb{R}^n$ that $x+h \in D$.

Firstly, we have $$g(x_0+h)-g(x_0)=f'(x_0+h)(u)-f'(x_0)(u)=\left[f'(x_0+h)-f'(x_0)\right](u) \quad (1)$$
Secondly, since $f$ have second dervative at $x_0$ that exist linear mapping $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^p)$ that $$f'(x_0+h)-f'(x_0)=A(h)+\vert h \vert_2\varphi(h) \quad (2)$$
with $\lim\limits_{h \to 0_{\mathbb{R}^n}}\varphi(h)=0_{L(\mathbb{R}^n,\mathbb{R}^p)}$.

From (1) and (2), we infer that $$g(x_0+h)-g(x_0)=A(h)(u)+\vert h \vert_2\varphi(h)(u)$$

I stuck here now.

I wonder that there exists linear mapping $A_1: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^p$ and function $\varphi_1:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^p$ that $A_1(u)(h)=A(h)(u)$ and $\varphi_1(u)(h)=\varphi(h)(u)$?

Comment: Can you define $\vert h \vert_2$?

Comment: @XiuweiLee $\vert \cdot \vert_2$ is Euclide norm.

Comment: The rest of us would just write $\|h\|$ here. What does "hence that $f$ [has] a second derivative at $x_0\in D$ mean? This makes no sense. You're supposing that $f$ is differentiable and that *in addition* $f$ has a second derivative at $x_0$? ("Hence" has a completely different meaning.)

Comment: Try to express $g$ as a composition of differentiable maps. Then, by the chain rule, it will also be differentiable, and you can calculate its derivative.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks for the feedback. My English grammar is not good. About why I write $\vert h \vert_2$ but not $\Vert h \Vert$, it because I want to distinguish between symbols.

Comment: @peek-a-boo I still not get it. How can I show $g(x_0+h)-g(x_0)=A_1(h)+\Vert h \Vert \varphi_1(h)$??